# Conversion form fields to JSON nested objects using DOJO

Tags: javascript, json, dojo

I am using DOJO 1.8 iand spring mvc. I want to convert my form fields to JSON objects and pass it to the controller. Using DOJO dom-form.toObject("myForm1") i am able to pass the Json to the controller if it is a simple object.

If my model object is having inner objects then the .toObject() is not able to convert that into nested JSON objects.

```
var formObject1 = domForm.toObject("myForm1");
    alert("hi");
    require(["dojo/json"], function(JSON){
        postData = JSON.stringify(formObject1);
    });

    dojo.byId("testdiv").innerHTML = postData;
```

and the Json I am getting is

> {"firstName":"12345","middleName":"Joanna","lastName":"Eliza","address.addrLine1":"add1","address.addrLine2":"add2","address.addrLine3":"add3","email":"12345"}

But I need as below,

> {"firstName":"12345","middleName":"Joanna","lastName":"Eliza",**"address":{"addrLine1":"add1","addrLine2":"add2","addrLine3":"add3"}**,"email":"12345"}

Does DOJO support this type of JSON conversion?

Comment: Are you sure that Spring MVC does not handle names like "address.addrLine1" correctly if you post your form? Have you actually tried to post it e.g. with `xhr.post({form: "myForm1", url: ..., ...})`?

Comment: i am using request.post.                                            'require(["dojo/request","dojo/dom-form"], function(request,domForm){
    request.post("http://localhost:8080/Caseview/saveForm", {
   data: domForm.toObject('myForm'),
      handleAs: "json"
    }).then(function(data){
      // do something
    }, function(e){
      // handle error
    });
  });' 
I have a model class with Address address as an instance parameter and Adress have this addressline1 as instance variable. if am passing address.addressline1  i am getting an excpetion as below...(see the below comment)

Comment: org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "address.addrLine1" (Class com.sfg.model.CallerName), not marked as ignorable at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@135d392; line: 1, column: 83] (through reference chain: com.sfg.model.CallerName["address.addrLine1"])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dojo has various method for this kind of task. Just look at the [documentation](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/dom-form.html) and choose a suitable solution.

Comment: Thanks for your immediate reply ....i tried with this domForm.toObject("myForm1") using this only.....but i am getting the json as {"firstName":"12345","middleName":"Joanna","lastName":"Eliza","address.addrLine1":"add1","address.addrLine2":"add2","address.addrLine3":"add3","email":"12345"}.But i need that in nested objects as mentioned above. In the link you have given doesn't say any thing about that....

Comment: You have the object representing the form, loop through it and regroup it.

Comment: ohhh ok ....that means I have to manually arrange it....DOJO doesn't give JSON in that way rite?

Comment: I don't think so. At least from what I understan from Your question. Input names are just names, no matter the prefix. :(

Answer (score 0):

A short function that will do the job:

```
// lang = require("dojo/_base/lang");
function deepenObject(/*Object*/ object) {    
    object = lang.clone(object);
    for(var key in object) {
        if(object.hasOwnProperty(key) && ~key.indexOf(".")) {
            lang.setObject(key, object[key], object);
            delete object[key];
        }       
    }
    return object;
}
```

Then just:

```
var result = deepenObject(formObject1);
```

See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/gaJ8C/